# How can i use mouse right click button in a listBox on selected index?

Tags: c#

I have this selected index event of a `ListBox`:

```
private void listBox1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{    
    if (listBox1.SelectedItem != null)
    {
        label4.Text = listBox1.SelectedItem.ToString();
        string startTag = "Url: ";
        string endTag = " ---";
        int startTagWidth = startTag.Length;
        int endTagWidth = endTag.Length;
        int index = 0;
        index = label4.Text.IndexOf(startTag, index);
        int start = index + startTagWidth;
        index = label4.Text.IndexOf(endTag, start + 1);
        string g = label4.Text.Substring(start, index - start);
        label4.Text = g;
        mainUrl = g;
    }
}
```

I want that after I selected an index(item) in the `ListBox` and I make now right click with the mouse on this index it will do something. But if I will make mouse right click button on any other area on the `ListBox` or the Form it won't do anything. Only if the mouse is on the selected index.

What I need to do is that the user will be able to remove/delete an item from the `ListBox`. 
I just don't know what is the best logic of how to do it when the user click the right mouse button.

Show I make it when the user first selected an item and only if the mouse is above/on this selected item ? Show I do it that if the user clicked mouse right button on any item it will select it automatic and do something ?

Im not sure wich way is better and logic and how to do it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just subscribe to the MouseDown of the Listbox, and use `IndexFromPoint` to check if the current item you clicked on is the selected item.

Here is an example:

```
private void listBox1_MouseDown(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
        if (e.Button == System.Windows.Forms.MouseButtons.Right)
        {
            int index = listBox1.IndexFromPoint(e.Location);
            {
                if (index == listBox1.SelectedIndex)
                {
                    MessageBox.Show("Selected item clicked");
                }
            }
        }
}
```